# Struct zero initialization methods

Tags: c, memset

Is

```
struct datainfo info = { 0 };
```

the same as

```
struct datainfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
```

What's the difference and which is better ?

Comment: Semantically the end-result would be the same on all now-running systems.

Comment: it is the same. One is syntactic sugar for the other.

Comment: @alinsoar You're assuming that null pointer is represented by all-bits-zero and that floating point zero is represented by all-bits-zero.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I believe in C you are allowed to assume the null pointer is 0. Can't in C++ though.

Comment: @Bathsheba C does not require null pointers to be represented by all-bit-zero. Even though the way of writing the null pointer is `0`, the implementation is expected to [convert `0` to whatever the internal representation is](http://c-faq.com/null/machnon0.html). It's [not even required that null pointers of different types have the same internal representation](http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No it is not the same. The former may end up as part of .bss initialization and the latter get executed in run-time. Depends on variable scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is the best way by a country mile, as it guarantees that the `struct` members are initialised as they would be for `static` storage. **It's also clearer.**

There's no guarantee from a standards perspective that the two ways are equivalent, although a specific compiler may well optimise the first to the second, even if it ends up clobbering parts of memory discarded as *padding*.

(Note that in C++, the behaviour of the second way could well be *undefined*. Yes C is not C++ but a fair bit of C code does tend to end up being ported to C++.)

Comment: To be honest, and maybe it's just the C++ programmer in me that's speaking, but I find `{}` clearer than the `{0}` form. A shame C doesn't accept the first form (without GNU extensions).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed, I wonder why C doesn't yet have the `{}`? But I'm far from being a C expert. Perhaps they have their reasons?

Comment: Wish I knew, because this is the the one thing that *always* trips me.

Answer (score 4):

Practically, those two methods are very likely to produce the same result. Probably on account of first being compiled into a call to `memset` itself on today's common platforms.

From a language lawyer perspective, the first method will zero-initialize all the members of the of the structure, but there is nothing specified about the values any *padding* bytes may take (in the individual members, or the structure). While the the second method will zero out *all* the bytes. And to be even more precise, there is no guarantee that an all byte zero pattern is even an object's "zero" value.

Since (if one knows their target platform) the two are pretty much equivalent in every way that counts for the programmer, you choose the one that best suits your preferences.

Personally, I favor the initialization over the call to `memset`. Because it happens at the point of declaration, and not in another statement, not to mention the portability aspect. That makes it impossible to accidentally add code in between that makes the initialization not run (however unlikely that may be), or be faulty somehow. But some may say that `memset` is clearer, even to a programmer reading it later that is not aware of how `{0}` works. I can't entirely disregard their argument either.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, the code is functionality equivalent. 
Using the x86-64 gcc 8.3 compiler

The code:

```
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    struct datainfo { int i; };
    struct datainfo info;

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
}
```

produces the assembly:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-4]
        mov     edx, 4
        mov     esi, 0
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    memset
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

while the code:

```
main()
{
    struct datainfo { int i; };
    struct datainfo info = {0};
}
```

compiles to:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

To my untrained eye, the two outputs are 11 instructions vs 6 instructions, so at least space is more efficient in the second implementation.   But as noted by others, the zero initialization method is much more explicit in its intent.

Comment: Did you compile the code with optimization turned on? Calling `memset` with fixed, small size should be a victim of the optimizer,

Comment: @harper There were no compiler options enabled. If you are interested in experimenting with compilation output from a range of compilers, you can try them out online here: https://godbolt.org